# Trouble with emacs .el file (Searching for program; permission denied) error

Tags: windows, emacs, lisp

I have emacs version 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.2.9200) installed on a Windows 8.1 machine.  I am trying to use the ledger.el distributed with John Weigley's ledger (version 2.6.1).  While the lisp file loads into emacs and seems to function (I have the .el file in the right place and my .emacs file refers to it), when I try to use the C-c C-a to add a new transaction based on an old transaction, I get the following error:

Searching for program: permission denied, ledger.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that you do not have a program named `ledger` installed in your `exec-path`.

If you do have a program named `ledger` installed somewhere then add its path (location) to the value of `exec-path`.

See the Elisp manual, node [`Subprocess Creation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Subprocess-Creation) for information about `exec-path`.

See also environment variables `PATH` and `EMACSPATH` in the Emacs manual, node [`General Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html#General-Variables).

Comment: Drew - this was an outstanding answer to my question!  Instead of just giving me an answer to try, you told me where to go look for the answer.  I was able to take your guidance and go learn enough to fix the problem - I was setting the path incorrectly.  I have since corrected my mistake and the program is working perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped.